# How to take over network-connection files from xubuntu into Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, modem, modem-manager

This is a not so advanced question, but users needs to know how to answer this:

Referring to strange network-connection with a modem, which seems to be a copy of the neighbour, I want to write over the files for network-connection in order NOT to deliver myself as copy to the neighbour. So which files do I have to take for this from my xubuntu installation (want to write over the Ubuntu files).

/etc/network

/etc/network-manager

/etc/apt

and which else files do I need to overwrite for the proper modem-connection ?!

> (elder Ubuntu 14.04.04 LTS has the output :
>
> home@user:~$ sudo apt-get update
>   0% [connection with dlink.com (12.130.207.110)] [connection with dlink.com > (12.130.207.110) ... here output breaks off ...
>
> home@user:~$
>
> )

thank you for answer (with bounty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the NetworkManager config files are in

```
/etc/NetworkManager/
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

There should be no network settings stored in the home directories but depending on how the modem is dialed up there might be some configuration
in hidden folders (i.e files and folders beginning with . that ls -a shows you) named after some of the dialup apps.

wvdial uses ~/.wvdial.conf and /etc/wvdial

you might also need these if the dates of the files look like you changed them.

```
/etc/chatscripts
/etc/ppp
```

Comment: - are there no else files affected, in case there is a doublette modem in the neighbourhood or do I see ghosts in bushes ???

Comment: sorry but i have no idea what you mean

Comment: strange - there was a modem in the neighbourhood which was the same modem like mine with dlink.com as doublette - this modem in the neighbourhood now disappeared ... ?

Comment: do you mean Wifi Access Point when you said modem ? and doublette i'm guessing is duplicate .  So this leads me to guess that you suspect someone nearby is trying to run a duplicate wifi network to your own and you don't want to connect to it.    If there is a wifi network of the same name and using the same encryption scheme and password then your wifi adapter will assume its part of the same network.

Comment: To avoid this happening you can edit the settings on the connection profile that you use to make it only use a specific BSSID (the binary identifier for the network) of your router. There will be a drop down list of BSSID's that have been seen advertising the SSID the connection is using.  If you have multiples select one , turn of your router , if it still connects then you have the BSSID of the one you want to avoid so switch it over.